# Select and show characters/string between specific delimiters in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I have the following format in a single string:

abcd**%HelloWorld;**df4?****Thisis;sf4er7?**Test**;sdf

From the above text,
  I want to grab HelloWorld in textbox1, Thisis in textbox2 and Test in textbox3.

Each of them lies in between "%;"s and "?;"s.

I want it to happen in single event. How do i do this in C#.net? Suggest me the fastest yet easiest way to get this done!

Comment: Use regular expressions to parse out your values? Or string.split if you're to lazy to learn regex :)

Comment: i think regex would be the better idea. I want something faster here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.
http://en.csharp-online.net/Manipulating_Strings_in_CSharp%E2%80%94Splitting_a_String

```
string input ="abcd*%HelloWorld;df4?*Thisis;sf4er7?Test;sdf"
input = input.Replace('%').Replace('?')
string[] splited = input.split(';')
```

Or Regex
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx

```
string input = "plum--pear";
string pattern = "-";            // Split on hyphens

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
foreach (string match in substrings)
{
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple case I'd use String.Split - something as simple as `string.Split(new string[] {"%;", "?;"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first unify the splitters like replace "%" and "?" with unique character like '|' or even space.

then split the string by the unified character that you set.

finely if you know the indexes you will fetch the array of the strings that returned from the splitting process and you will get in each index a word or the phrase you want

Comment: Yeah! I appreciate your hints :) Thank you very much for the help!